# Read data from google sheet use it globally in client side html

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've been stuck with this for weeks, I think it's the time to reach for some tuition.

I'm aiming at building a quiz web app using GAS:

- I have a google spreadsheet with the questions (let's call it DATABASE)
- **I am not able to import the questions** into a variable that is usable globally in my client side (the DATABASE).
- My logic of the web app so far is as following
  1) Read DATA from the sheet
  2) Use DATA to build QUESTION and CHOICES in html
  3) Click button of a choice and check if it is correct, then do something
  4) Go to next question
  5) Ideally, questions and choices will be shuffled.

Things I've tried and I haven't managed to do right:

a) Deploy a QUESTIONS.html with the values of the DATABASE --> can't access the values from other functions in html scripts

b) Use google.script.run (also tried with successHandler), can't access the values of the DATABASE outside the function()

c) Use properties, can't access the values of the properties (DATABASE) in client side

Any ideas are welcome.

CODE.HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="quiz">
      <p id="question"></p>
         <div class="buttons">
            <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
            <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
            <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
            <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
         </div>
  </div>

<script>   
  function createQuestions(data){
  //THIS WORKS FINE FOR QUESTION 1
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = data[0][0];
  document.getElementById("choice0").innerHTML = data[0][1];
  document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML = data[0][2];
  document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML = data[0][3];
  document.getElementById("choice3").innerHTML = data[0][4]; 
 }  
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createQuestions).getData();
 //HOWEVER I DON'T KNOW HOW TO GET FROM HERE TO QUESTION 2
 //I CANNOT CREATE A SECOND FUNCTION BECAUSE THE DATA IS NOT ACCESSIBLE
</script>
</body>
</html>

CODE.GS

function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
  html.setTitle("QUIZ APP");

  return html; 
};

function getData(){
  return SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID").getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();  
};
```

Comment: Can you share your implementation of `getData()`?

Comment: I've found a way to iterate questions, however, as far as my little knowledge of this goes, the only way I have to work with my data is inside functions and through calls to google.script.run.withSuccessHandler

I'm looking for a way to have all the data from the sheet stored in a client side variable.. if this makes any sense

Comment: Use the `window` object in the DOM to store which question is currently displayed.  Your app needs to know what the current question is, so that the `getData()` function can get the next question.  In your function `createQuestions()` I would write a statement that stores the current question as a number.  `var currentQuestion = window.joseRuizCurrentQuestion; if (!currentQuestion) {currentQuestion = 1;} else {currentQuestion = currentQuestion + 1} window.joseRuizCurrentQuestion = currentQuestion;//update the question number`  Then pass the currentQuestion number to `getData(currentQuestion)`

Comment: Then your `getData(currentQuestion)` function knows what the current question is, and can get the next question.  If you don't want the questions to always be in the same sequence, then you'll need some code to randomly generate a number, and then keep track of which numbers have been used.  So, instead of `window.joseRuizCurrentQuestion` you could have an array of already used question numbers.  `window.joseRuizCurrentQuestion = [5]`  question 5 has already been asked.  `window.joseRuizCurrentQuestion = [5,3,9] `  Questions 5, 3 and 9 have already been asked.